# Javascript regular expression to remove double backslashes

Tags: javascript, regex

Having some trouble with backslashes regular expressions. I want to remove all dual backslashes (or any multiple of 2) that exist on any string property of an object. I do not want to remove single backslashes nor the last backslash in an odd number of backslashes (e.g., leave one backslash remaining in a set of five continuous backslashes \\\\\ -> \).

The code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/59Zau/

```
//removes all dual backslahes on all string properties on an object
var removeDualBackslash = function (obj) {
    var ret = null;
    if (typeof(obj) == "string") {
        obj = obj.replace(/\\\\/g,"");
        return obj;
    } else if (typeof(obj) == "number") {
        return obj;
    } else if (typeof(obj) == "array") {
        ret = [];
    } else {
        ret = {};
    }
    for (var key in obj)
        ret[key] = removeDualBackslash(obj[key]);
    return ret;
};

var oJSON = {"t4m_data_in":{"no_data":"No data \\passed in."}};

oJSON = removeDualBackslash(oJSON);

console.log(oJSON.t4m_data_in.no_data);​
```

As you can see from the console.log, one of the backslashes remains. Does anyone know what regular expression I need to remove both of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your JSON string. The `"\\"` there is already a single backslash.

```
>> console.log("No data \\passed in");
No data \passed in
```

Are you sure you don't want to just remove all backslashes instead?

```js
obj = obj.replace(/\\/g,"");
```

Doing so would remove literal backslashes like `"\\"` but would still preserve other escape sequences like `"\n"` because in those cases the backslash is just in the string literal, not in the actual string.

Comment: Makes sense--I suppose then I could just do obj = obj.replace(/\\/g,""); because any backslash present in the string at the time of .replace was originally dual backslash.

Comment: Well, this function will eventually get applied strings that contain escaped JSON... that's where my headache multiplies. I think this will work though, I'll accept this answer, thanks!

Comment: @ElliotB: Why do you even need to replace backslashes? Ideally you should not even have to do this...

Comment: I'm working with a proprietary backend whose native method to convert JSON to record structure errors when two or more consecutive backslashes are passed in.